# how to open a link on same page automatically

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome

i have to open all links with "VEZI" in a new tab or access and download them simultaneously without manually clicking on it.

can anyone suggest something ? tried an add on on chrome, didn't work properly.

link to webpage http://jurisprudenta.csj.md/db_col_civil.php

Comment: almost every browser will simply stop that happening

Comment: isn't there any script that can be applied so it can access a html or jquery function button ?

Comment: Is `"VEZI"` part of URL at `.href` of element?

Comment: as far as i could see is part of a function :
`function() {
                            var ids = jQuery("#list").getDataIDs();
                            for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
                                var cl = ids[i];
                                vezi = "<a href='search_col_civil.php?id="+cl+"' target='_blank'>VEZI</a>";
                                jQuery("#list").setRowData(cl,{VEZI:vezi})
                            }
                        }
                                             })`

Comment: You could do this in PHP: Grab all the links you want from the page and then simply download them.

Comment: This will be blocked by the popup blocker. If you could get around it, then so could the adware people that the popup blocker was designed to stop.

Comment: Kiko, if i grab all the links then this would not fulfill the purpose of what i am searching/trying to do because i would have to do it manually. i made a script in bash using a for and the IDs of the pages and downloaded all files i needed, with grep -R i filtered the files i needed.